# Try to compile python wrapper

Tags: c++, setuptools, python-3.8

I'm trying to use the repo:
https://github.com/PierreFritsch/OpenCV-Python-C-Module-for-Image-Processing

Compilation on my 18.04 Ubuntu computer works properly. However, when I try on my 20.04 Ubuntu computer, I get the following error when I try to import the library:

```
python3.8
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import helloWorld
/home/xavier/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.15) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/helloWorld-1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/helloWorld.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5pbcvt16fromMatToNDArrayERKN2cv3MatE
```

I use python3.8 on my second computer. How come the compilation doesn't work on my second computer?

I looked at the generated library. When I look at the library `helloWorld.abi3.so`, I can't find the symbol with the same same:

```
readelf -s /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/helloWorld-1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/helloWorld.abi3.so | grep fromMatToNDA -A 2 -B 2
     6: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __cxa_atexit@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4 (3)
     8: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN5pbcvt16fromMatToNDArr
     9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND PyArg_ParseTuple
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN5pbcvt16fromNDArrayToM
--
    72: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
    73: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2
    74: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN5pbcvt16fromMatToNDArr
    75: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND PyArg_ParseTuple
    76: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN5pbcvt16fromNDArrayToM`
```

Comment: `c++filt` says the symbol is `pbcvt::fromMatToNDArray(cv::Mat const&)`.  Do you have that available?

Comment: In the so file, I can't find that symbol I only have _ZN5pbcvt16fromMatToNDArr

Comment: The function is available in the file pyboostcvconverter.hpp and define in pyboost_cv3_converter.cpp : PyObject *fromMatToNDArray(const Mat &m)